# Prevent Gitlab CI from creating merge request pipeines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following structure for my **gitlab-ci.yml**,

Pipeline basically has 3 stages

- first: consist of job1-3
- second: consist of job4
- final: conist of job5

All of the jobs use `only/except` while `job3` uses `rules:if`,
Using this created a 'merge request pipeline' on our CI which just run the 'first stage' containing only 'job3'

```
---
image: node:dubnium

stages:
  - first
  - secondary
  - final

job1:
  stage: first
  script:
    - echo "Stage one - Job 1 lint"
  except:
    - master
    - main
  tags:
    - docker
    - linux
  allow_failure: false

job2:
  stage: first
  script:
    - echo "Stage one - Job 2 audit"
  except:
    - master
    - main
  tags:
    - docker
    - linux
  allow_failure: false

job3:
  stage: first
  rules:
    - if: $SKIP_TEST != "true"
  script:
    - echo "Stage one - Job 3 script"
  tags:
    - docker
    - linux
  allow_failure: false


job4:
  stage: second
  tags:
    - docker
    - linux
  except:
    - master
    - main
  script:
    - echo "Stage one - Job 4 scan"

job5:
  stage: final
  tags:
    - docker
    - linux
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - echo "Stage one - Job 5 build"
```

I have tried doing like

```
rules:
    - if: $SKIP_TEST != "true"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: never
```

But the above snippet just results in the job being skipped entirely.

Also when trying the snippet below, this results in job3 being skipped on our pipelines, but creates a 'merge request pipeline' with first stage containing job3 alone

```
rules:
    - if: $SKIP_TEST != "true" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: never
```

My question is
Is there a way to all in all prevent Gitlab from creating a 'merge request pipeline'?

Comment: try with 

rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

Answer (score 0):

For merge request pipelines deactivation it is possible to use [workflow keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html) with rules:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
```